# Outsystem .doc file- Error Wrong Local header signature: 0xE011CFD0

Tags: outsystems

I'm using `Outsystem` and my goal is to export a Word 2007 file (`.doc` file), filled starting from the Word template (`version 2007. doc file`) with the parameters entered by the user, but I'm incurring in the following error:

> Wrong Local header signature: 0xE011CFD0

If instead a `.docx` file is used as template, no problem is shown.

What should I do?

Comment: Seeing as the OutSystems platform has no out-of-the-box way of dealing with Word files, you must be using a custom component. Please expand the question with more context. In any case, DOC and DOCX are very different formats (docx is XML based), so I will not be surprised if a component only supports one - the DOCX being the most obvious one.

Comment: Your question seems to not to be clear, please add some more relevant things.